# How to break line in a single row of <table>? <tr>

Tags: php, html, html-table

I am creating a program in  which I am fetching data from database and showing it in a table. I don't know how much record will be fetch from the database, but I have to print 3 records in a single line, and next 3 in the another line. I have created the following program in the its printing all the records in the same line. I want it to limit this to 3 and after 3 records change line and print the next 3 record in the other line.

```
<body>   
    <table border="2px">
        <tr>
        <?php
        for($i=0; $i<=5; $i++)
        {
            echo "<td> $i </td>";
            $i=$i++;
        }
        ?>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you use the following:

```
for($i=0; $i<=7; $i++){
    echo ($i%3 == 0) ? '<tr>' : ''; //Start a row
    echo "<td> $i </td>";
    echo ($i%3 == 2) ? '</tr>' : ''; //End a row after the third item
}
echo ($i%3 == 1) ? '<td></td><td></td></tr>' : ''; //End row adding two cells if only one is present after loop
echo ($i%3 == 2) ? '<td></td></tr>' : ''; //End row adding one cell if only one is present after loop
```

`$i=$i++;` Is NOT needed in your code as it is defined when the `for` loop is initialised

**Complete Code**

```
<table border="2px">
    <?php
    for($i=0; $i<=7; $i++){
        echo ($i%3 == 0) ? '<tr>' : '';
        echo "<td> $i </td>";
        echo ($i%3 == 2) ? '</tr>' : '';
    }
    echo ($i%3 == 1) ? '<td></td><td></td></tr>' : '';
    echo ($i%3 == 2) ? '<td></td></tr>' : '';
    ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<?php
echo "<tr>";
for($i=0; $i<=5; $i++) {
  echo "<td>".$i."<td>";
  if( $i % 3 == 0 ) 
    echo "</tr><tr>";
  }
echo "</tr>";
?>
```

Comment: You missed the `$` in your for loop! Also, this code will output an empty row _if_ the loop ends on the third cell in a row (i.e. if `$i%3==0`)

Comment: @Steven Thanks for that. I have fixed the typo/omission.

Comment: No problem, I tried to.. But it wouldn't let me change such a small mistake/typo! haha

Answer (score 0):

Just another sample, Try something like this to exactly break table to `3` columns with any records count. in this case `$i` is: `<= 5`

```
echo "<table border='2px'>";
for ($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    if($i%3 == 0) echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td> $i </td>";
    if($i%3 == 2) echo "</tr>";
}
if($i%3 != 0) echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
```

Also You don't need to `++` $i inside for!! Remove `$i=$i++;`

Answer (score -1):

```
<table border="2px">

<?php
echo "<tr>";

for($i=0; $i<=5; $i++)
    {
    echo"
    <td> $i </td>";
    if($i % 3 == 0)
    echo "</tr>";
    $i=$i++;
    }

?>
</table>
```

Comment: oops.. I forgot that condition. My mistake :( . jeff made it right.

Comment: This will not output rows as intended because your `if` condition is incorrect... The first row will have only one item in it.